# Why doesn't flexing work for this spinner?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, spinner

The output-
[Out put of the code][1]

I tried margin auto, justifying, alignment, and more but nothing worked. I am new to programming so I'm not able to understand where the mistake is. Can anyone please help me out!!

***Code of the component***

````
const LoadingSpinner = () => {
    return (
        <div className='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mx-auto' >
            <img className='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mx-auto' src="https://www.w3tweaks.com/images/essentials/css-loaders/window-icon-like-loader.gif" width={'300px'}alt="" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoadingSpinner;

***Whre I used it***

return (
        <section>
            <div className='fruits'>
                { fruits[0]?.name ?
                    (fruits.slice(0, 6)).map(fruit => <Fruit button={button(fruit._id)} fruit={fruit} key={fruit._id} />) : <LoadingSpinner/>
                }
            </div>
            <button onClick={()=>navigate('/manageitems')} className='manage-btn'>Manage Inventories</button>
        </section>
    );```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTltu.png
````

Comment: The way you have it, `<LoadingSpinner />` component will be rendered as a direct child of `<div className='fruits'>`.  That is, unless you also make the `.fruits` a flex container, its child `<LoadingSpinner />` will not be a flex child.

Comment: So `align-items` and `justify-content` affect the _children_ of where they're set. That means you're centering the `img` inside your `div`, not centering your spinner inside your fruits container. As @BumhanYu says, you'll need to move the flex up a level in the DOM.

Comment: @BumhanYu how can I do that? I am new to programming.

Comment: In your `<LoadingSpinner />` component, you're giving the parent `div` a combination of classNames. In a nut-shell, the same (or similar) set of classNames should be present for your `<div className='fruits'>` JSX element.